# Can I use a resistor with higher resistance for driving an LED?

Tags: led, resistors, diodes

I'm very new to electronics and wanted to use a couple of LEDs.

I used an online calculator and it says I need a 40-ohm resistor. Can I use a 100-ohm resistor instead of 50?

What happens if I do?

Comment: Include a schematic that shows **HOW** you want to use / connect the LEDs and resistors. Usually, using a higher value resistor in series with LEDs will make less current flow and make the LEDs burn op less brightly. You might not notice much difference though. So go ahead and try the 100 Ohms, it will probably just work.

Comment: Which LED, link to datasheet? At which voltage, and at which current you want to use it?

Comment: If you only have 100 Ohm resistors, you could also use two of those in parallel which would effectively make a 50 Ohm resistor.

Comment: Saying "LED diodes" is saying "light-emitting diode diodes". Just say "LEDs". A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Answer (score 2):

Some things to consider:

[image: Some LED datasheet]

(Image source: [Farnell / Multicomp - red LED datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1498852.pdf))

Always check datasheets. But regularly you can say a red LED has a max **continuous** current of 20 mA.

At that current this LED has a Vf forward voltage of:

[image: Another picture of the datasheet]

See left graph: 2.2V.

That means if the LED is next to a resistor and a 9V output; R=V/I R=9-2.2/0.020 = 340 Ω. At least. A resistor is a current limiter, the LED is not. It can use practically unlimited current and without resistor it will brighten very much for a very short moment.

As you see in the last picture when the (forward) current changes, so does the intensity of the LED. Even with a very low current it still works, but just very dim.

But hey, the max current was 20mA? Yes continuous. In the datasheet is also stated that the max peak current is 100 mA; so for a blinking LED this is possible. But the restriction then is 1/10 duty cycle, 0.1 ms pulse width.

Answer (score 1):

LEDs are rated for their ‘typical’ current, which ranges between 10 and 20mA. You can however obtain useful brightness at much lower currents, as low as 1 or 2 mA, as the eye is more sensitive to lower intensities. High-efficiency LEDs will perform especially well at these reduced drive currents.

Experience: set-top boxes.

Comment: Between 10 and 20 mA for common cheap LEDs, anyway. I've used high-efficiency LEDs that are only rated for 5 mA maximum, and typically run at 1 to 2 mA. And LEDs for lighting may be intended to run at hundreds of mA.

Answer (score 1):

In general the LED won't be as bright with 100 Ω as with 50 Ω. Assuming that the circuit has no additional purpose for consuming the current, it will still 'work'.

In electronics you will find few exact answers to questions like this. This is because the requirements are not strict, and because the conditions vary. For example, the efficiency of the LED, the temperature, the ambient light level etc. Part of the design process is to find a reasonable compromise  between unsafe (above spec. for the LED) high current level, and too low brightness (at low supply voltage and perhaps an LED with extreme low brightness).

In addition component tolerances, temperature and supply voltage changes affect the calculations. When these result in a conflict -- such as a min supply the LED is not bright enough, and at high supply the current exceeds the LED's spec, then you might need a different circuit (e.g. a regulator for the current).

Answer (score 1):

Well there is not one particular answer to it since it will vary case to case depending on the circuit, power source and other components. In general 100 ohm will cut the current to half which may effect LED brightness. You can experiment with using a variable resistor and adjust to check the brightness.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

- Yes, you can use a higher value
- As a result, the current trough the LED will be lower and it will be less bright

**Longer answer:**

It's good to see that you're doing some research and know that you should use a resistor to connect an LED to a voltage source.

It's used like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGObI7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now why is this resistor needed?
LEDs are diodes (as the name suggests) and share some traits. One is, that they have a highly non linear relationship between current and voltage. Up to a certain voltage the LED conducts almost no current (Voltage depends on type of LED, typically 1.6V for red LEDs and about 2.4V for blue ones. The other colors are in between). If the voltage is above that treshold, the LED starts to conduct a lot of current rapidly which would lead to the destruction of the LED if the current is not limited in some fashion.

That's what the resistor R1 is for. It's a current limiting resistor. We mostly use a simplified calculation that's *good enough* for most cases. We assume a constant voltage for the LED we use (let's say 1.6V for a red LED). Than we just subtract the LED voltage from the voltage of the source and use [ohms law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) to find out what resistor we need to get the required current.

Most small LEDs can be run with around 10mA to 20mA. But for most applications you'll aim for 1mA-5mA for a LED that should just signal something. Otherwise they get uncomfortably bright to look at.

So what happens if you take a higher value resistor? The current trough the LED will be lower and therefore the LED will be a bit less bright. IS this a problem? Technically no, but it really depends on your application. If you just want it to shine, it's absolutely ok to have a higher value resistor.

Btw: you can get almost any value resistor. But the most common ones are in the [E-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_series_of_preferred_numbers) which is basically a logarythmic distribution of values. For most cases Values for the E6 series are the most commonly used and cheapest available. Just keep the numbers {10, 15, 22, 33, 47, 68}*10^x in your head and round your resistor values to the closest of those values...